# Header in navigation view is clickable. How to disable it?

Tags: android, navigationview

I'm trying to disable the "touch highlight animation" when touching the header. `onNavigationItemSelected()` is correctly only called when a menu item is touched. But when I touch the header, there is an animation.

I've tried `setEnabled(false), setClickable(false) setLongClickable(false), setAnimation(null), setFocusable(false)`, but it still showing. I cannot find a methods for manipulating the header. (other than addHeader)

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that updating to the latest version of the design library allowed for the following:

```
View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.header_view, mNavigationView, false);

headerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Consume input from header view. This disables the unwanted ripple effect.
    }
});
```

I am quite confident that I tried this without luck before updating, though.